# How can I make my plotted circle smaller in R?

Tags: r, size, geometry, figure

When I try to plot a circle using RStudio, I only see part of the circle. This happens when I use draw.circle from the plotrix package and when I use grid.circle from the grid package.

This is what I see:
[image]

I just want to have a normal circle. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried plotting a smaller circle?

Comment: use `?draw.circle` and you'll see that you need to mess with `radius`

Comment: Yes, I want a circle with radius 1 (which is already small), but I changed it to 0.1, which still gives me the lowest-left quarter. When I change it to 0.01 I see the full circle, but it's very small.

Comment: refer to my comment in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark here.

`draw.circle` only adds to the current plot. If the result cuts off the circle, the reason is that you didn't create a plotting region with room to view the circle.

Compare:

```
plot(-3:3,-3:3,type = "n")
draw.circle(1,1,1)
```

with this:

```
plot(0:1,0:1,type = "n")
draw.circle(1,1,1)
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! I needed to "zoom out" to see my circle completely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
draw.circle(0.1,0.1,0.1)
```

Idea is that the coordinates start from the left bottom corner where the axes meet. If you set like 1,1,1 the radius would exceed the boundaries and you would get a quarter circle.

Comment: just scale it up and make sure all three numbers are the same. you will realise that the circle gets bigger and bigger but there is a limit beyond which your circle will exceed the plot.

Comment: But I want to see a circle with centre(1,1) and radius 1. Is there no way?